# Executing wrong relationship vlaue in $args in wp_Query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i am trying to fetch data form database for my custom plugin and post type. my query arguments should be like

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'products',
    'post_status'=> 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
      array( 'key'=>'product_commercial',
       'value'=>'on',
       'compare'=>'=' 
    ), 
      array( 'key'=>'product_exterior',
       'value'=>'on',
       'compare'=>'='    
    )
  )
);
$search_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But i am trying to add meta key values dynamically like :

```
$inner_arrays=array();
$count = 0;
foreach($values as $value){
if($value){

        $inner_arrays[$count]['key'] .= $value;
        $inner_arrays[$count]['value'] .= 'on';
        $inner_arrays[$count]['compare'] .= '=';
        $count++;
}
}

    $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'products',
    'post_status'=> 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
    $inner_arrays
)
);
```

//values are some random values (say fetched from db).

Now when i print the query using `echo "<pre>Last SQL-Query: {$search_query->request}".'<br/>';`

it displays

```
    Last SQL-Query: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ( 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'product_commercial' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'on' ) 
    **AND** 
    ( mt1.meta_key = 'product_framed' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'on' ) 
    **AND** 
    ( mt2.meta_key = 'product_horizontal' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'on' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'products' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

PROBLEM: i am using " **relation => OR** ", but getting "**AND**" in sql query. Where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$args['meta_query']` is assigned the following:

```
array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    $inner_arrays
)
```

If you were to inspect this, e.g. by doing `print_r( $args['meta_query'] );`, you'd see:

```
Array
(
    [relation] => OR
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    key => product_commercial,
                    value => on,
                    compare => =
                ), 
            [1] => Array
                (
                    key => product_exterior,
                    value => on,
                    compare => =
                )
        )
)
```

In other words, the `$inner_arrays` array has *itself* become a sub-array of `$args['meta_query']`.  As documented under [Custom Field Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters):

> **Important Note:** `meta_query` takes an **array** of meta query arguments **arrays** (it takes an array of arrays) - you can see this in the examples below. This construct allows you to query multiple metadatas by using the **`relation`** parameter in the first (outer) array to describe the boolean relationship between the meta queries. Accepted arguments are 'AND', 'OR'. The default is 'AND'.

Consequently you are combining your elements of `$inner_arrays` using the default relation of `AND`, whilst then combining the result of *that* with any other members of `$args['meta_query']` (there aren't any) using the explicit relation of `OR`.

You must instead either append each element of `$inner_arrays` to `meta_query`, or else just set `$inner_arrays['relation'] = 'OR'`.